# Acessar pasta dropbox no Android

Tags: php, android, apache, dropbox

Existe alguma maneira de acessar a pasta do dropbox?

Tenho o seguinte problema, estou desenvolvendo um webapp que vai funcionar local em tablets de um evento, então para isso estou usando o app AndroPHP e gostaria que meu diretório do apache fosse uma pasta do dropbox, pois assim eu poderia atualizar todos os aplicativos dos tablets, apenas atualizando minha pasta no dropbox e assim sincronizando com os tablets, alguem conhece alguma maneira de se fazer isso?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dropbox tem uma API pra isso https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/start/php

Fácil de integrar, creio que não vai ter problemas.

================================================

Vamos lá então como solicitado:

=========================================

**Instrução básica ao APP**

- CRIAR UMA APP NO DROPBOX
- Crie uma APP no DROPBOX  https://www.dropbox.com/developers/apps/create
- Escolha a opção "Dropbox API app" depois selecione "Yes - My app only needs access to files it creates."
- De um nome para a APP e em seguido você será redirecionado para a tela de config do APP,
- defina a url de retorno onde voce irá gravar o token de autenticacao

Ex:

```
http://localhost/dropboxAPI/end_auth.php
```

- Nesta mesma página vai aparecer sua APP_KEY e APP_SECRET - que irá usar para autenticar a APP.

=============================================

- INSTALAR COMPOSER

  https://getcomposer.org/

=============================================

- Dentro da pasta da sua APP neste caso usei a pasta "dropboxAPI/" crie um arquivo chamado "composer.json" 
  coloque o seguinte codigo nele

  ```
  {
    "require": {
      "dropbox/dropbox-sdk": "1.1.*"
    }
  }
  ```

  - Entre na pasta de sua APP pelo CMD ou terminal já com o arquivo "composer.json" criado.

EX:

```
/var/html/dropboxAPI/

e digite o comando: 

composer install
```

- Aguardar o termino da instalação dos pacotes.

=============================================

- CRIANDO OS ARQUIVOS
- Para este exemplo que estamos fazendo crie os seguintes arquivos

  - index.php
  - end_auth.php
  - config.php
- Arquivo abaixo 'config.php'

  ```
  <?php
  session_start();
  function pre($arg){
      echo "<pre>";
         print_r($arg);
      echo "</pre>";
  }
  require  "vendor/autoload.php";
  define('DROPBOX_KEY'    , 'sua key');
  define('DROPBOX_SECRET' , 'seu secret');
  define('APP_NAME'       , 'ShowRoomEvent');
  # inicia classe
  $app = new Dropbox\AppInfo(DROPBOX_KEY,DROPBOX_SECRET);
  # metodo token verificacao
  $tokenCsfr = new Dropbox\ArrayEntryStore($_SESSION,'dropbox-auth-csrf-token');
  # pede autenticacao
  $auth  = new Dropbox\WebAuth($app,APP_NAME,'http://localhost/dropboxAPI/end_auth.php',$tokenCsfr);

  ?>
  ```
- Abaixo codigo o 'end_auth.php' (ou o arquivo que voce definir na URL da APP)

  ```
  <?php
  # inicio arquivo end_auth.php
  # RECEBE O TOKEN DO DROPBOX
  require 'config.php';
  list($getToken) = $auth->finish($_GET);
  if( isset($getToken) && !empty($getToken)){
      # ARMAZENAR NA SESSAO OU BD
      $_SESSION['user_token'] = $getToken;
      header("Location: index.php");
  } else{
     echo "Erro ao gerar autenticacao";
  }
  #fim arquivo end_auth.php
  ?>
  ```
- Arquivo index.php com os exemplos basicos

  ```
  <?php
  require 'config.php';
  # se voce colocar na url ?logout=true
  # vai limpara a sessao e pedir autenticacao novamemente
  # lembrando que voce pode armazenar essa info no BD, XML etc...
  if( isset($_GET['logout']) ){
     unset($_SESSION['user_token']);
  }
  # verifica se tem token
  if( ! isset($_SESSION['user_token']) && empty($_SESSION['user_token'])) {
     # se nao tem token pede permissao para o usuario
     $url = $auth->start();
     header("Location: " . $url);
  }
  # o token ja foi armazenado na sessao conforme arquivo 'end_auth.php'
  $user = new Dropbox\Client($_SESSION['user_token'],APP_NAME,'UTF-8');
  $usuario = $user->getAccountInfo();
  pre($usuario);
  echo "<br/><br/>";

  /* EXEMPLO UPLOAD
   * Para fazer upload para o dropbox voce ja deve
   * ter o arquivo localmente ou fazer o upload e depois
   * enviar par ao drop
   *
  */
  $arquivo = fopen("cascata.png",'rb');
  $tamanho = filesize("cascata.png");
  # onde o nome cascata_no_drop.png deve ser o nome que
  # vai ser usado no dropbox lembre de colocar / antes do nome
  $user->uploadFile("/cascata_no_drop.png",Dropbox\WriteMode::add(),$arquivo,$tamanho);

  /*
   * EXEMPLO DOWNLOAD
   * informar o path do arquivo no drop
   * informar novo nome para o arquivo "fopen mode 'wb'"
   */

   $user->getFile("/cascata_no_drop.png", fopen("cascata_vinda_drop.png","wb"));

  /*
   * LISTA O QUE TEM NO DROPBOX
   */
  $lista = $user->getMetadataWithChildren('/');
  pre($lista);
  ?>
  ```

Comment: Oi rafaelphp. Se você reproduzir aqui um exemplo mínimo funcional do código a sua resposta fica muito melhor (porque deixa de depender tanto do link - que se estiver fora do ar não ajuda em nada o leitor) e ganha o meu +1. :)

Comment: @LuizVieira da uma olhada tenta ai tmb ve se precisa corrigir algo ou explicar melhor. abs

Comment: Não tenho como testar porque não tenho o ambiente instalado. Mas, como prometido, toma meu +1. :)

Comment: Mas isso serviria no caso para eu trabalhar local no tablet, sem precisar de conexão com a internet? Por que a idéia era que eu trabalhasse em uma pasta local, no caso o tablet teria dropbox instalado nele. E mesmo se a pessoa não tivesse conexão com a internet o app teria de funcionar. A parte do dropbox, seria de que se eu atualizar um arquivo, eu atualizar todos os tablet pela pasta do dropbox, assim que os tablets acessassem a internet.

Comment: @LeonardoPatricio, Sua pergunta era para fazer a APP localhost acessar o dropbox e nao que teria que usar o dropbox offline, cara acho dificil sem internet voce conseguir fazer isso com o dropbox pois o que voce quer é uma solução que trabalhe com o dropbox sincronizando todas pastas e isso só é possivel com internet.

Comment: @LeonardoPatricio, Porem ai esta um exemplo de como usar a api e funciona perfeitamente em localhost. Mas pelo que entendi você pode fazer isso sem ter que usar o dropbox, apenas com PHP upload e download de arquivos, é só voce deixar um tablet como servidor assim todos os outros tablets vao acessar esse, não é preciso ter o androPHP em todos tablets apenas em um. Voce pode colocar um roteador sem internet apenas para fazer uma rede local e conectar os tablets por esse router sem acesso a internet, isso vao lhe permitir fazer a aplicação offline com um tablet configurado como servidor.

Comment: @LeonardoPatricio, ou deixe um notebook como servidor e com IP fixo tipo: 192.168.1.100 assim o server local fica mais rapido e voce podera usar pelo navegador dos tablets, acessando no chrome por exemplo:  http://192.168.1.100/minhaapp. Creio que essa seja a melhor opção sem usar o dropbox.

Comment: Sim para o local do evento vai existir um servidor, porém devido ao grande número de redes wifi no local, as redes wifi caem com frequência, e esse mesmo sistema pode ser usando quando um funcionário da empresa for visitar um cliente, assim através do aplicativo do tablet ele consegue gerar um pedido, e ele não está dentro de nenhum wifi e pode ou não ter 3g, logo não se pode depender da internet, apenas a atualização dos arquivos da aplicação que depende da internet, e acredito que a melhor forma para se resolver isso seria usando o dropbox, que assim conseguiria atualizar todos por 1 lugar.

Comment: Eu gostei da sua resposta @rafaelphp estarei estudando essa api do dropbox, porém gostaria de saber se você ja conhecia algo que pudesse me atender perfeitamente.

Comment: @LeonardoPatricio, agora entendi melhor, voce pode fazer com que o script do dropbox salve na sua pasta de sincronizacao, assim quando o tablet estiver com internet vai sincronixar automatico.

Comment: Porque o que eu inicialmente estava pensando era apenas o meu apache ter como pasta root uma pasta do dropbox, assim ficaria mais simples para mim, mas não sei se isso é possível.

Comment: ou o caso seria de ter uma classe da aplicação que conseguisse atualizar os arquivos, puxando de algum servidor online, no qual eu disponibilizaria os arquivos atualizados, assim eliminaria o uso do dropbox, mas também não sei se isso é possível com o php.

Comment: @LeonardoPatricio, sim é possivel. Creio que voce ja desvendou o misterio.

Comment: Estarei buscando informações para resolver esse problema, toma os 50 pts pela dedicação em tentar ajudar